# Can you use a weapon sheathed in a Ruby Scabbard in a Opportunity Attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, opportunity-attack

Can you use a weapon sheathed in a [Ruby Scabbard](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=item&id=2361) in a Opportunity Attack?

> Property
>   This scabbard resizes to fit any light blade or heavy blade. You can draw a weapon from this scabbard as part of the same action used to make an attack with that weapon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. The Scabbard's ability is a Free Action, and you can use Free Actions at (pretty much) any time including when it isn't your turn.

[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=118):

> Free actions take almost no time or effort. A creature can usually take as many free actions as it wants during any turn, including other creatures’ turns.